# Jqgrid,dataEvent does not work for edittype:custom

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I'm new to jqgrid, I have a column whose edit type is custom.

Once the row data is edited , I want the row to be saved on blur (when i click outside of the selected row), for this purpose i made use of dataEvent , but it does not work.

I'm using Jqgrid version4.1.

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue.

I have attached a piece of my code below:

```
{ name: 'Roles', index: 'Roles', align: 'left', editable: true, 
  edittype: "custom",
  editoptions: {custom_element: renderRoleColumn, custom_value: roleColumnValue,
                dataEvents: [{ type: 'blur',
                               fn: function (e) {
                                    alert("roles");
                               }
                             }]
               }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right. The current implementation of jqGrid don't use `dataInit` or `dataEvents` on the (see [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.common.js#L453-470) of jqGrid don't call `options = bindEv(elem,options)` like for all other edittypes). The problem is only that I am not sure that it's a bug. In [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom) of jqGrid described really all steps which are done in case of `edittype: "custom"`.

I don't see that it's a problem. You can make any bindings inside of `custom_element`. You don't posted any code of `renderRoleColumn` and `roleColumnValue` which you use, but if you would bind `blur` event handle to the custom element which you returned it will be work.

**UPDATED**: Your custom formatter `renderRoleColumn` returns `<div>` with `<select>` and `<input>` elements as children. The `<div>` can't have focus and will don't process `blur` event too. So you should bind `blur` to the child elements `<select>` and `<input>`. The code can be like the following

```
function renderRoleColumn() {
    //... your current code which generate HTML fragment in the roleDiv as string

    // create DOM element from the HTML fragment with jQuery wrapper
    var $custom = $(roleDiv);

    // make binding to children
    $custom.find('select,input').blur(function (e) {
        alert('blur on ' +
            e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() +
            ' id=' + e.target.id);
    });

    return $custom[0]; // return roleDiv as DOM element
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks . The blur event binds to 'input' only, it does not bind to the 'select' , actually i want to save the option selected in the select , can you please help me on this.

Comment: @Divya: You are welcome! Sorry, but I tested the code with `addRolesCounter = 0` and it works. You can try replace `.blur` to `.focusout` and additionally set focus explicitly with `.focus` on `.click`. I mean to do something like `$custom.find('select,input').click(function (e) { $(e.target).focus(); });`. You can also try to set focus on the 'select' or 'input' using 'TAB' key. In the case you will be sure that the focus are set and the `blur` should also work.

Comment: Thank you so much, now i'm able to get the .focusout working ,I have one more question, on focusout , i want the selected option from the dropdown to be saved on the cell . Can you please help me in getting that done. I'm sorry i'm new to jqgrid and finding edittype:custom complicated.

Comment: Now when i press enter , the selected value in the dropdown box ,gets saved in the cell. I want the same operation to happen on focusout.